# Select table cell as a group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grouping

In this table, I want to select multiple cells as a group.
You can select a target cell by clicking on it, 
but I also want to **click and drag** to cover multiple cells as a group.

Is that possible to achieve that without any plugins (just use JQuery)?

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

The array content will be:
`["3-2", "3-3", "4-2", "4-3", "5-2", "5-3"]`

Here is what I try so far:

```js
var group = [];

var columnIndex = 7,
  rowIndex = 10;
var $tableContainer = $('#tablecontainer'),
  $table = $tableContainer.append('<table border="1" id="table1"></table>'),
  $thead = $table.find('table').append('<thead></thead>'),
  $tbody = $table.find('table').append('<tbody></tbody>');

var $columnNumber = "";
var $tdNumber = "";
for (var col = 1; col <= columnIndex; col++) {
  $columnNumber += "<th>Column " + col + "</th>";
  $tdNumber += "<td style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; color:red'></td>";
}

$thead = $thead.append('<tr><th>0</th>' + $columnNumber + '</tr>');

for (var row = 1; row <= rowIndex; row++) {
  $tbody = $tbody.append('<tr><td>Row ' + row + '</td>' + $tdNumber + '</tr>');
}

$('#table1 > tbody > tr >  td').hover(function() {
  var colIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
  var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
  $(this).attr("title", 'Row: ' + rowIndex + ', Column: ' + colIndex);
  // console.log('Row: ' + rowIndex + ', Column: ' + colIndex);
});

$('#table1 > tbody > tr >  td').click(function() {
  var colIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
  var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
  group.push(rowIndex + "-" + colIndex);
  console.log(group);
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  // console.log('Row: ' + rowIndex + ', Column: ' + colIndex);
});
```

```css
#table1>tbody>tr>td:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tablecontainer"></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functionality you want to achieve is possible by using `jquery mouseover` function.
I made a fiddle to get the desired output as you expect.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjeqL914/1/)

Hope this helps you in solving the issue.

-Help :)

Comment: Most of that JS code seems to be more or less identical to the one from this question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50218143/1427878 … so, is this really your own work? If not, you should at least mention that.

Comment: @Help Thank you very much. Your answer helped me in achieving the desired result. Upvote from my side.